# Protecting a webpage with an authentication form

Tags: iis

I have created an employee webpage with a lot of company info, links, etc., but I want to protect the page because it contains some confidential company information.

I am running IIS7.5 on Windows Server 2008 R2, and I already have the site setup as a normal, non-protected site. I want all active directory users to have access to the site. This is not an intranet site, it is exposed to the internet.

I tried setting it up using Windows Authentication, but I had problems with multiple login prompts, etc. I just want a simple form for users to enter their credentials and have access to the site, and I need it to query the AD for login.

I've searched the web for a guide on this, but I can't seem to find one that fits my situation. This is not a Web App. It is just a simple html site.

Does anyone have any suggestions or a link to a guide on this?

Thanks so much! -LB

Comment: Is this a single web page or a site? And are you using ASP.NET?

Comment: It is a single page. I am not using ASP.NET. I am just hosting html files, css files, and images.

Comment: Forgive me, but I have to ask: Is it a good idea to have a public site query the AD directly? Of course, it could be an internal site, in which case it's a little less bad? :)

Answer (score 1):

Even if you are not using ASP.NET web forms you can use [ASP.NET Web Forms authentication](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security/introduction/security-basics-and-asp-net-support-cs) as the site is hosted by IIS.

If your web.config you can [specify directories](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316871) that require authentication, and can scope that authentication to whatever users or groups you want:

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms" >
        <forms loginUrl="login.aspx" name=".ASPNETAUTH" protection="None" path="/" timeout="20" >
        </forms>
    </authentication>
<!-- This section denies access to all files in this application except for those that you have not explicitly specified by using another setting. -->
    <authorization>
        <deny users="?" /> 
    </authorization>
</system.web>

<!-- This section gives the unauthenticated user access to the Default1.aspx page only. It is located in the same folder as this configuration file. -->
    <location path="default1.aspx">
    <system.web>
    <authorization>
        <allow users ="*" />
    </authorization>
    </system.web>
    </location>
<!-- This section gives the unauthenticated user access to all of the files that are stored in the Subdir1 folder.  -->
    <location path="subdir1">
    <system.web>
    <authorization>
        <allow users ="*" />
    </authorization>
    </system.web>
    </location>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to use PHP there is a very simple solution to protect a single page: http://www.totallyphp.co.uk/password-protect-a-page